# рандомные улучшения как в Vampire Survivors(нужно выводить на экран 3 кнопки с ивентами из пула кнопок и чтобы они не повторялись)

Tags: c#, unity3d

нужно выводить на экран 3 кнопки с ивентами из пула кнопок и чтобы они не повторялись(условно посредине экрана).
у меня получилось в рандомные числа без повторений но что делать дальше ? Как мне вывести эти кнопки ?

```
public GameObject[] G_Object;
public GameObject[] S_Object;

public List<int> TakeList = new List<int>();

private int randomNumber;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    TakeList = new List<int>(new int[G_Object.Length]);
    for (int i = 0; i < G_Object.Length; i++)
    {
        randomNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, (S_Object.Length) + 1);
        while (TakeList.Contains(randomNumber))
        {
            randomNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, (S_Object.Length) + 1);
        }
        TakeList[i] = randomNumber;
        //G_Object[i] = S_Object[(TakeList[i] - 1)]; тут где то должно что то произойти 
    }
}
```

Comment: В целом, ты эти рандмные числа можешь использовать как индексы массива с нужными тебе бафами. Но в этой игре используется не совсем рандом, игра оценивает, насколько ты сейчас силен, как быстро ты убиваешь волны и предлагает тебе менее сильные решения для твоей текущей сборки

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за ответ , немного помог. Вот что у меня получилось и вроде работает

```
{
public RectTransform[] G_Object;
public GameObject[] S_Object;
public RectTransform Canvas3;

public List<int> TakeList = new List<int>();

private int randomNumber;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

    Canvas3=GetComponent<RectTransform>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
    {
        TakeList = new List<int>(new int[G_Object.Length]);
        for (int i = 0; i < G_Object.Length; i++)
        {
            randomNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, (S_Object.Length) + 1);
            while (TakeList.Contains(randomNumber))
            {
                randomNumber = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, (S_Object.Length) + 1);
            }
            TakeList[i] = randomNumber;
   
            Instantiate(S_Object[(TakeList[i] - 1)], G_Object[i].transform.position, G_Object[i].transform.rotation, Canvas3);
           

        }
    }
}
```

}